# App is closing Unexpectedly in Android

Tags: android, web-services, web-applications, web

I am unable to figure out the thing that why my simple webview app is getting closed unexpectedly. Even if the Eclipse is not throwing any error.

Here is the screenshot http://pbrd.co/YNWFVw

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.testwebview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/m");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**testwebview Menifest** :

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testwebview.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Add your Logcat output...

Answer (score 5):

Get the web view after setting the content view i.e

`WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);`  // this returns null because you haven't set contentView, so when you try to access it, it will throw `NullPointerException`

So get the webView reference after `setContentView` like this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

**Edit:**

For your second query, webview opening url in default browser, use this code

Webview by default uses browser to open the url, we need to do something like this

```
webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/m");
          return true;
           }});
```

Comment: thanks, but now the default browser is opening the site. I want to open the site in webview only.

Comment: @jeeveshkumar check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229494/webview-link-click-open-default-browser

Answer (score 0):

Always call through to the super's lifecycle callbacks before you do anything else, i.e. you should call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` before `setContentView(...)`.

What's actually causing the crash is most likely a NullPointerException. Calling `setContentView(...)` is what actually creates your views. If you call `findViewById(...)` before that, it will return `null` because your layout hasn't been inflated yet. Use LogCat in Eclipse's DDMS to get the stack trace, and you'll find that you're calling `.loadUrl(...)` on `null`.

Here's what your onCreate method should look like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/m");
}
```

Another note: don't use `fill_parent` for your heights and widths -- it is deprecated. Use `match_parent` instead.