# How to force open of a new browser in Android (from a webpage)?

Tags: javascript, android, html, browser

I have an application that reads a webpage.

The problem is that my application buit-in browser can't read the content correctly. But if I open the link with the chrome of firefox application it works fine in the mobile.

I have control only over the webpage. So I would like to to know:

- It's possible to a web page to make the mobile application open the
  browser selector like Firefox, Chrome (like    target="_blank" in
  html champ).
- There is any web tool to process the javascript online and render a simpler view to my mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to your webview:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) 
        {
            view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } 
        else
        {
           return false;
        }
   }
});
```

For more info, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229494/webview-link-click-open-default-browser).

Comment: But in this case the code is added in the mobile application right? I have access only to the page web.

Comment: Hmm... now I get it... would something like this be useful?

https://github.com/eusonlito/jquery.applink