# Android how to make my web view displaying a php page with a link to connect to the Android Market?

Tags: php, android, webview, google-play

I have an application where I display a web view that connects to my website php file so I can offer up to date notes, so I'm trying to place a link in it so that the user can download other apps of mine, the problem I have faced is that when the links is clicked it opens google play inside the web view instead of opening the android market and so users have to login in to their google account first to download my app, if the android market opens everybody is log into it so they can just press the download button.
so here is the code I'm using in my php file

```
 <a href="http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.other.app">Get my other FREE App</a>
```

reading the developer guide it says that when a link like this is clicked in a webpage from inside a Android device you can choose to open it with the browser or the market app, so why am I not able to choose.
Thanks for any advice.
EDIT: 
here are a couple screen shots
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a device specific issue. You probably clicked on a market link before and set market links to open in the brower by default. To fix this open app settings and then click on your brower. There will be a section that says something like "you've set this app as the default app for somethings" below that text there will be a button that says something like "clear defaults". Clear your defaults and then try your link again. (Also, I should note that for play.google.com links to work your market app needs to up to date)

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583264/support-for-other-protocols-in-android-webview) question is probably actually what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but I have been trying to do what you suggest but there is no default settings on it, and even clearing the data or cache of the browser it still not giving me any options, it just connects to google play website.

Comment: That's really odd, even if your browser isn't set as the default for anything it still should show the "launch by default" section with the button grayed out. Have you tried scrolling down to make sure that its not there?

Comment: Remember its in the app settings, you get to these by going to settings from your home screen. Its not in the settings within the app.

Comment: @ someoneHuman, You know if I type the url in my normal browser as http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.other.app I don't get send to the android market but if I type http://market.android.com/search?q=pname:com.my.other.app I do, but neither of them work in my web view.

Comment: oh, well that probably means that your version of the market is not totally up to date. Also, see my edit.