# Open up chrome custom tab from within Android webview: CustomURL handler & insecure content warning

Tags: android

I'm trying to open up a Chrome custom tab from within a webview inside of an Android app.   In order to do this, I figured I could register a custom URL handler(customtab://www.myurl.com/). The error I'm running into is that chromium(the webview) is blocking the custom URL handler due to an insecure content error (This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.).  The URL is https.   Even adding `webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);` on the webView didn't work.

Any ideas on how I can register this custom handler as "secure"?

Comment: Post a simple project at github demonstrating that behavior.

Comment: Where is the page hosted? On the web? What are the http headers set by the web server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use web intent to open url in chrome

> Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
>
> webIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
>
> getActivity().startActivity(webIntent);

Comment: The issue is that we need to intercept a dynamic URL from the webview - and it seems a custom URL handler is the only way to do that.

Comment: He wants to open custom tabs, not Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this method on the Webview to skip ssl errors

```
public synchronized void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler,SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();                      
      }
```

Comment: webview doesn't have an onReceivedSslError method to override, WebViewClient does. When I override WebViewClient's onReceivedSslError it does not get called.

`[chromium] [WARNING:web_contents_impl.cc(3535)] XXXXXX ran insecure content from customURLHandler://YYYY
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'XXXX' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'customURLHandler://YYYY'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.", source: XXXXX (0)`

Comment: How does this answer the question? What TLS error are you trying to intercept?

Answer (score 0):

I am open my custom URL in web view in android with follow below process.

Design your webview as full screen like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in you .java file add below code in onCreate method

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        getWindow().setLayout(windowwidth, windowheight);

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);





        try {
// here i call progressdialog which is load still the page is not load //properly
            Constants.ShowProgressDialog(MyActivity.this, "", "Please wait...");


            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i("", "Processing webview url click...");
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i("", "Finished loading URL: " + url);
// dismiss the progressbar after load the web page in webview.
                    Constants.disMisProgressdialog();
                }


                @Override
                 public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                }
            });

                webView.loadUrl("<your url>");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If still any issue please provide me your url I'll check and provide you the code.

Hope your problme resolve.

Make sure provide permission in Manifest file.

> "<"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />" (remove the quatation mark)

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: How does it answer the question?  --- bro as per user ask the question that he/she having issue regarding url of http and https so i provide the solution that here he/ she can load any url in internal android browser.  have you any reegarding this than feel free to ask in place of down point :-|

Comment: What part prevents "This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." error when user clicks on `customtab://www.myurl.com/`?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to register a `WebViewClient` in your `WebView` and override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method to support your own scheme:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  if (url.startsWith("custometab://")) {
    // TODO: start custom tabs for the url.
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514668/94363)

The problem is: how do you know when clicking on `customtab://www.myurl.example.com/` if you should open `http://www.myurl.example.com` or `https://www.myurl.example.com`?

- You could either introduce `customtab://` and `customtabs://`
- or do some manipulation of the URL `customtab://http/www.myurl.example.com`

But in fact, I don't think we need a custom scheme at all if you want to open all links with custom tabs. Just use:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  // TODO: start custom tabs for the url
  return true;
}
```

Comment: See my reply to Vardaan Sharma below - the webview client isn't even receiving the custom URL.  It seems that chromium is blocking the URL from being sent to the webview client.

Comment: I was suggesting to _not_ have a custom scheme. So what custom scheme is blocked?

Comment: And I think my answer is correct, except if your web server defines a Content-Security-Policy which says to not load anything but 'https://". Check your HTTP config.