# How to use external browser on web view Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I convert WordPress website to android app, in my website lots of external links i need to open external links browser like telegram, in telegram all external links open in external browser in the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem SOlved guys thanks for your replays

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583264/support-for-other-protocols-in-android-webview) (from [sven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280384/sven))

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://"))) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

As @peshkira has given a good solution, but I would suggest to use [CustomTab](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs).

With Custom Tabs you can get instance of browser without creating a web view. As it provide navigation awareness, the browser delivers a callback to the application upon an external navigation. You can modify and update following -

> Custom menu
>
> Color of the address bar
>
> Custom action button
>
> Custom enter and exit animations

Setup for CustomTab -

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"
}
```

In your code, Open a CustomTab -

```
String url = ¨https://paul.kinlan.me/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

You can save up to 700 ms when opening a link with the Custom Tabs by connecting to the service and pre-loading the browser.

Most browser do support CustomTab like Chrome, Samsung Mobile Broswer, Microsoft Edge etc.
Please follow [Custom Tabs Best Practices.](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs/best-practices) Here is a [gitHub example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/master/demos/custom-tabs-example-app).

---

**Edit**

As you mentioned in your comment *"every post have 1 external link"*, then you following options -

1. Create a `WebView` to open link
2. Use intent to open device external browser
3. Use `CustomTab` to open instance of browser

I think behavior of all three is very well explained via [this gif](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs/performance.gif).

Now, to show all the posts in your app, I believe you are using a `RecycleView`, so you can decide from three choices, you can listen for click on one of the post by using a click listener on that post, something like follows -

```
postItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handleClickOnLink(postUrl);
    }
});
```

Now in the body of your method `handleClickOnLink(String postUrl)` you can use your code to decide how you want open the link.

As I have mentioned above, Using `CustomTab` will be one of the choices, which I think will be a good option in this case, so you can have an implementation of method as follows -

```
public void handleClickOnLink(String postUrl){
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

    //setting toolbar color 
    builder.setToolbarColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    //can be more modification as builer.setTitle() and more

    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getContext(), Uri.parse(postUrl));
}
```

If there is a device with a browser which doesn't support `CustomTab` then device default browser will be open.

Result will be something as follows -

[image]
Happy Coding !

Comment: bro in webview how to work? already i have a wordpress site i covert site to app, in that site every post have 1 external links so how to do this

Comment: well I'm not sure how you have converted your wordpress site into your app, if you're already using a WebView to show content of your wordpress site then using CustomTab is not in picture at all, you should go with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` suggested by @peshkira.. if you are using some `WebCrawler` or some other way to get information from your site to show in a list then please check my edit.

Comment: more over, I don't use telegram but I did check the external link behavior on telegram on one of my friend's phone and I found telegram do have implementation of `CustomTab` in their code for external links.

Comment: Dear Sharma, I need to do other side, i need to prevent going to the default browser, i am loading a asp web site to my web view, when press log in button the web view is requesting to go to the default browser. i need to stop it and going to the main form thought android web view. how do i fixed this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`WebViewClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) to your webview and override the [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) method. This will give you a callback when a link is clicked and you can inspect the url and decide if you want to open in the webview or open it in the external browser.

For example something like:

```
private class MyCustomWebClient : WebViewClient() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?
        ) = if (interceptUrlLoading(request?.url?.toString())) {
            true
        } else {
            super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean =
            if (interceptUrlLoading(url)) {
                true
            } else {
                super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)
            }

        private fun interceptUrlLoading(url: String?): Boolean {
            return if (url.equals("telegram url ...")) {
                startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))) 
                true
            } else {
               false
            }
        }
}
```